# How to efficiently reshape one column matrix to many specific length columns by moving specific interval

Tags: matlab

The input is an *`N`*-by-*`1`* matrix. I need to reshape it to *`L`*-by-*`M`* matrix. The following is an example.

Input:

```
b =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Set length = 18, Output:

```
X =

 1     2     3
 2     3     4
 3     4     5
 4     5     6
 5     6     7
 6     7     8
 7     8     9
 8     9    10
 9    10    11
10    11    12
11    12    13
12    13    14
13    14    15
14    15    16
15    16    17
16    17    18
17    18    19
18    19    20
```

Because I have a very big matrix, using a loop to reshape is very inefficient. How can I improve the reshape speed?

Comment: "Because I have a very big matrix, use loop to reshape is vary unefficiently." How do you know?

Comment: Thanks. Not always 1:N, the data is random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example output matrix `X` is the perfect matrix to index a vector of length `N` to get what you want. It's also very easy to create using `bsxfun`:

```
N = 20;
b = rand(N,1);

M = 3; %// number of columns
L = N-M; %// Note that N-M is an upper limit for L!
idx = bsxfun(@plus, (0:L)', 1:M)

X = b(idx)
```

Comment: Thank u very much, that's perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: @StonerYancy Good to hear. In that case you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what [`im2col`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) (from the Image Processing Toolbox) does:

```
b = (1:20).';            %'// example data
L = 18;                  % // desired length of sliding blocks
x = im2col(b, [L 1]);    % // result
```

Comment: Appreciate. The code is terse, but costs 2-3 times time than @Dan.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `horzcat`. For example:

```
function X = reshaper(b,len)

diff = length(b) - len + 1;
X = b(1:len);

for i=2:diff
    X = horzcat(X,b(i:len+(i-1)));
end
```

You could probably remove the for loop with some further thought.

Comment: Thanks. If the _diff_ is two large, the loop is unefficiently.

Comment: NB do not use `diff` as a variable name as `diff` is a very useful MATLAB function!

Comment: Good point I overlooked cobbling that together. Useful to learn about *bsxfun*.